# Is $[0, 1) \times (0, 1)$ homeomorphic to $(0, 1) × (0, 1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

I know how to show $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ is not homeomorphic to $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ by a compactness argument. Is there such an argument that shows $[0,1) \times (0,1)$ is not homeomorphic to $(0,1) \times (0,1)$? If not, what is the best way to show that they're not homeomorphic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both spaces every point has a local basis consisting of simply connected open environments. In the latter space, removing the point from those simply connected environments always leads to a set that is no longer simply connected. In the former space there exist points (which we could call the "boundary" if it were not such a charged term in a topology course) where removing the point from the simply connected open environment leaves a simply connected set.

Come to think of it: in the former space there exist points whose complements are simply connected. Not so in the latter.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

Consider the  [$1$ point compactification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_extension) of each  space. For $[0,1)\times (0,1)$ it's the closed disk, for $(0,1) \times (0,1)$ it's  the sphere.

Comment: I upvoted because it was an interesting approach, but I feel this is sort of cheating, since proving that the sphere is not homeomorphic to the closed disk is not obtained by a simple compactness argument.